# Unsure of how to query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently taking a "beginner" database class working with SQL and the teacher has been less than helpful and the provided information makes no sense.
For context, my assignment asks to find which region within the database has the most repairs done. I'm not sure how to write the query to pull this information. We are using Codio for MySQL, I have included a screenshot for the current table I am working out of and how the attributes are set up.
[image: Databases and Tables]

Answer (score 0):

to get the count for ec´very state you Group by state and use count which would gove you the number of repairs per state. The rest is sorting by the numbers and LIMIT the result to 1

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) countr FROM PartsinMaintenets GROUP BY state ORDER BY countr DESC  LIMIT 1;
```